# Show Window from another method and thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, splash-screen

I have an init method in which I create a thread and a window is displayed
This is my application code

```
public static SplashWindow _splashWindow;

        private static ManualResetEvent ResetSplashCreated;
        private static Thread SplashThread;

        public static void Init(SplashWindow splashWindow)
        {
            _splashWindow = splashWindow;
            ResetSplashCreated = new ManualResetEvent(false);

            SplashThread = new Thread(() => ShowSplash(_splashWindow));
            SplashThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            SplashThread.IsBackground = true;
            SplashThread.Name = "Splash Screen";
            SplashThread.Start();

            ResetSplashCreated.WaitOne();
        }

 public static void ShowSplash(SplashWindow splash)
        {
            splash.Show();

            ResetSplashCreated.Set();
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
        }
```

now when i call this code:

```
SplashHelper.Init(new anim());
```

I get an error in the `splash.show();` line

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'
```

Comment: WPF has a UI thread in which handles all UI-related calls such as opening windows, progressbars, etc. Why would you event want to achieve this?

Comment: The window **must** be shown in the same thread that owns it. This means either you give the thread that owns it a message-pump, or you make sure the thread that owns it already has a message-pump (e.g. create it in the main UI thread) and then use that thread's dispatcher to invoke your accessing code (the call to `Show()`) in that thread. See duplicates. You are creating the `Window` object in a different thread from where you use it. You should probably just skip the thread stuff and show it in the original thread. Use a background thread for whatever is currently blocking your main thread.

Answer (score 3):

You *cannot* create the window on one thread and `Show()` it on another.

You will have to both create the thread and call `Show()` in your `ShowSplash` method (or on the calling thread).

If you look at the [source code of Show](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Window.cs,31852a8904b66b47), you'll see that the first thing it does is to call a `VerifyContextAndObjectState()` method.

This method checks whether you are on the thread on which the window was originally created. If you are on another thread, it throws the `InvalidOperationException` that you are currently getting.

Comment: thank you so how can i pass window to method without creating it?

Comment: That's the thing. You can't. A window should be in one thread only.